# JAXB Marshalling - Reference is pulling and inserting entire object details inside XML

Tags: java, xml, reference, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying todo JAXB marshalling and running with strange problem.  I have three objects in one xml named Column, Row and Table

The ***table*** element has references to Column ID and Row ID. In Hibernate, I've one -to-one relation mapped (via many-to-one relationship))

When I generate the xml, I see that in place of ID, the entire record detail tag is getting inserted in my xml.

**What I want:**

```
<Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" >
    <Column>
         <Column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/>
    </Column>
    <Row>
        <Row id =1 name=" " desc="" id="">
           <Row id = 2 name="" desc="" id="" />
        </Row>
        <Row id = 3 name=" " desc="" id="" />
    </Rows>
    <table>
         <table name="" RowID="" measureID="" filter="" expression="" product="" dataset="" datatype="" subreport="" />
    </table>
</Hierarchy>
```

**What I'm getting**

```
<Hierarchy name="" desc="" title="" >
    <Column>
         <Column name="" desc="" group="" id=""/>
    </Column>
    <Row>
        <Row id =1 name=" " desc="" id="">
           <Row id = 2 name="" desc="" id="" />
        </Row>
        <Row id = 3 name=" " desc="" id="" />
    </Rows>
    <table>
         <table name=""  filter="" expression="" product="" dataset="" datatype="" subreport="" 
         <name =""/>
         <RowID>
            <id>1</id>
            <name></name>
            <desc></desc>
        </RowID>
        <measureID>
            <id>1</id>
            <name></name>
            <desc></desc>
         </table>
..............
    </table>
</Hierarchy>
```

I've defined the following relationship in my hibernate mapping file

```
 <many-to-one name="RowID" column="RowName" 
    class="com.abc.Row" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" not-null="false"></many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="ColumnID" column="ColumnName" 
    class="com.abc.Column" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" not-null="false"></many-to-one>
```

**In class I've defined the relationship as**

```
public class Table{
private id;
private Row rowID;
Private Column columnID;

..getters/setters
}
```

Can somebody pls advise as I'm new to JAXB

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `Row.id` property with [`@XmlID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html) and your `Table.rowID` attribute with [`@XmlIDREF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlIDREF.html).

Comment: I tried to annotate with XMLID and XmlIDREF. But my id is int datatype and XMLID expects it to be a string data type. In my Database, we have int column for the ID.

Comment: @Sam https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/15/pluggable-ididref-handling-jaxb-20 or convert in additional getter/setter or try an additional `@XmlAdapter`.